# .obj file imported on 2.82 doesn't consider separated meshes, while blender 2.79 does

Tags: mesh, import, versions

as the title says, version 2.82 sees the .obj file as a merged mesh, while if i open it with blender 2.79 it divides it correctly in the different meshes that compose the object and i can select each one of them. 
Is there a way, a parameter to set, in order to see the .obj divided structure also in 2.82? 
Or is it a not fixed bug?
Any suggestion is appreciated,
thank you very much.

Comment: If the mesh parts are disconnected you can switch to edit mode and use *Mesh > Separate > By Loose Parts* (P > By Loose Parts).

Comment: thank you so much @RobertGützkow

Answer (score 1):

If the imported object consists of disconnected mesh parts then you can use *Mesh > Separate > By Loose Parts* (<kbd>P</kbd> *> By Loose Parts*). In order to move the origin to each separated object use *Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*.